# Are function calls expensive in GLSL (for PowerVR chips)?

Tags: glsl

My assumption is that the GLSL compiler simply inlines all function calls, making them inexpensive. However, if function calls in GLSL implemented stack frames etc etc then they could be quite expensive. Does anyone know whether GLSL function calls are expensive at all?

Comment: I think the answer here is going to depend on the device, OS, and even version of the OS. For example, an iOS engineer told me that some short functions are inlined in their compiler, but what functions are inlined depends on the OS version (the shader compiler has improved significantly with each iOS version).

Answer (score 6):

Generally, function calls *should be* inexpensive even when not inlined, as no such thing as a stack frame exists (no recursion in GLSL!). Therefore, as such, a function call shouldn't be a forbidding overhead on any architecture (maybe 1-2 cycles).

However, function calls often happen in the context of a conditional branch, such as for example `if(foo) bar(); else baz();`, which per se are very expensive on GPUs when branches within a workgroup are divergent (that is, not all threads take *exactly* the same path).
If only a single thread takes, or *could* take, a different path within a workgroup, the GPU must either execute both paths followed by a conditional move (the usual case on previous-generation hardware), or a sync point is (implicitly) inserted on newest-generation hardware. In this case, only the path that is taken is evaluated by each thread (which arguably saves some power) but effectively all threads run lockstep, and the short path takes exactly as long as the long path. Worded differently, all pixels (or vertices, or work items) in the workgroup are processed as fast as the *slowest* in the group.

Answer (score 1):

Function calls can be expensive, dependent of your device. I suggest you take a look at the GLSL optimizer by Aras (From Unity):

https://github.com/aras-p/glsl-optimizer